# How to handle http status codes in express from http post response and pass along to the angularjs controller

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to handle various http status codes from my node/express and pass the response back to the angular. i get an error that Cannot set Headers after they are sent to the client. How do i Handle this based on response and also log for various http codes in nodejs?

```js
app.post("/employees", function(req,res) {

    var ServerOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://localhost:5001/api/empData',
        body: req.body,
        json: true,
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    request(ServerOptions).then(function (Response) {
        res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(401).json({message: "unauthorized"});
        console.log("Unauthorized");
        res.status(404 || 500).json({message: "error"});
        console.log("Error");
        res.set("Connection", "close");
    });

});
```

Comment: what is request function is returning?? Please give us the full code or please describe what request function doing??

Answer (score 0):

According to angularjs documentation on [$http](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http), when server returns status other than 200, "error" callback is invoked.

Try placing your code for handling 401 status inside `.error()`.